# Cors issue on an Angular / .NET Core project

Tags: angular, cors, httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm unable to get data out of my http request. On the server side I have the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
    services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddCors(options => 
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder
               .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
               .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
        
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "KYCDB API");
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

The project also has windows authentication on, anonymous off.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51721",
       "sslPort": 49321
    }
}
```

And on the angular side i got a component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  currentEmployee$: Observable<Employee>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentEmployee$ = this.userService.getCurrentEmployee();
  }
}
```

and an interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

When the page loads i get 2 warnings and an error

Warning: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:51721/employee/current. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Warning: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:51721/employee/current. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Error: Http failure response for http://localhost:51721/employee/current: 0 Unknown Error

What do i need to correct?

Comment: everything runs smoothly if I comment out the app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Comment: I see some mismatch in your URLs. You define CORS with `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`, launch with `http://localhost:51721`, and possibly redirect to another HTTPS-enabled URL. Try to setup all valid origins in the `WithOrigins` call.

Comment: Isn't WithOrigins the place where I put all client urls? That's why i put Angular there. The launch url I also use in the angular project inside the environment.ts file.

Comment: Yes, if your client Angular app is hosted on `http://localhost:4200`, then it is correct. At first I thought you serve the client from the ASP.NET app as well.

Comment: I can't understand why everything works if i remove the https redirection. also swagger doesnt work on https.

Comment: Try to set the client app to go to the HTTPS API endpoint right away. Maybe Angular does not follow redirects (from HTTP to HTTPS) automatically.

Comment: For the first Warning Reson `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`,you can try to set in StartUp.cs like this `builder.WithOrigins("xxx.xxx.xxx").AllowAnyHeader();`

Comment: @JosefBláha when i set in angular the https as base url then i get cors errors with or without the https redirection on the server

Comment: @YiyiYou you mean builder.WithOrigins("127.0.0.1:4200") ? i tried, same result unfortunately, as i was saying below, this may be an issue due to corporate settings

Comment: I means you can add `.AllowAnyHeader()` after your cors,maybe like `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:xxxxx").AllowAnyHeader();`.If it is not helpful,I find a link about [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin#:~:text=The%20response%20to%20the%20CORS,operating%20within%20the%20current%20origin.&text=The%20exact%20directive%20for%20setting%20headers%20depends%20on%20your%20web%20server.).

Comment: @YiyiYou no luck, maybe i need to create a certificate for the dev environment

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a difficult question so there could be a number of reasons it doesnt work but Ive run into a similar issue and resolved its by altering the cors invocation in the Configure() function. The Configure() function is a gets called during runtime and acts as an http request pipeline so in some cases order of execution matters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-configure-method)

You could try the following:

Change the current:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
        
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "KYCDB API");
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(); // Move this

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

To:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
        
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "KYCDB API");
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(); // Here

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Hence the first operation in the http pipeline would be to validate cors. I rate this is a fair bet as from your question it sounds like you dont get an app initialise error but rather a runtime client request time error. I dont know for certain if this will solve the problem but maybe it helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i tried. i tried every fu..... order! Microsoft actually says to put redirection first, then routing, then cors. Im starting to believe this issue is related to the corporate environment. i'll try to replicate this at home 2nite.